# Inserting value into row

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, insert

So I have a table with a few columns, and two of them are 'FirstName' and 'LastName'. I want to create a third column that combines both these columns into a username. So I created a username field in my model, but I'm really new to C#, MVC and programming and don't know how to tell my controller to combine the 'FirstName' and 'LastName' values and insert them into the row.

These are my attempts so far. Am I close?

```
//AdministrationController:

          [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Administration administration)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var f = administration.FirstName;
            var l = administration.LastName;
            var fl = f + l;

            foreach (var w in administration.Username)
            {
                db.Administrations.Add(fl);
            }
            db.Administrations.Add(administration);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");  
        }

        return View(administration);
    }
```

Comment: will this column be able to be updated in the future? If not, you could use a calculated column in the database to join them for you.

Comment: @jhinkley how would you do that?

Answer (score 0):

on Sql server you can create a computed column

```
ALTER TABLE [tablename]
ADD username AS firstName + lastName
```

not sure of the syntax for other DBs

Comment: Figured it out: administration.Username = fl;